# Selecting Max value of a column based on conditions of two other rows

Tags: sql, powerbi, max

Wish to obtain max value of Tag against each ASC_ID (which is duplicate in nature for same file type set at a unique occasion),in order to remove the duplicate rows and reduce file size,

```
ID / FILE TYPE / TAG
dhb-dhbv-001 / SI / 1
dhb-dhbv-001 / RS / 3
dhb-dhbv-023 / SI / 1
dhb-dhbv-023 / SI / 5
dhb-dhbv-099 / SI / 4
dhb-dhbv-099 / TDB / 1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce what you expect?

```
SELECT ID
, MAX(TAG) as MAX_TAG
FROM table
GROUP BY ID;
```